# Reading CSV with newlines within row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using Pandas to read a CSV file but some of the rows will continue on the next line and the `delimiter(")` will be at the start of the next line. I'm trying to find a parameter for 'pd.read_csv' that will fix it but after reading the documentation, I still not sure if there is one.

Ex:

```
"0","","0","0","0","0","0

","0","0","0","0","0","0"
```

In other words,

```
"0","","0","0","0","0","0\r\n","0","0","0","0","0","0"
```

Comment: Can you please add your Pandas code?

Comment: Original input.

Comment: tabla = pd.read_csv(file, sheet_name='x')

Comment: `sheet_name` is not a parameter of `read_csv`, but `read_excel `. Check your code. If your records are properly escaped, then `read_csv` should cope with it by default.

Comment: You are right about sheet_name. However, I have the same problem with both, read_csv and read_excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    with open(file, 'rU') as myfile:
        filtered = (line.replace('\n', '') for line in myfile)
        for row in csv.reader(filtered):
```